# autocomplete google address replacing previous value and is slow

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have created 3 classes as below to get address of locality after typing few letters but it replaces previous value and sometimes its slow.I really appreciate any help to fix this issue.Thanks in Advance.

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    AutoCompleteTextView atvPlaces;
    PlacesTask placesTask;
    ParserTask parserTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        atvPlaces = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.atv_places);
        atvPlaces.setThreshold(1);  


        atvPlaces.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {               
                placesTask = new PlacesTask();              
                placesTask.execute(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            }
        }); 


    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);                

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url 
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                        sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
     }  

    // Fetches all places from GooglePlaces AutoComplete Web Service
    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... place) {
            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            String url = null;
            try {
                url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+URLEncoder.encode(place[0], "utf-8")+"&sensor=false&components=country:US";


            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service in background
                data = downloadUrl(url);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;        
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // Creating ParserTask
            parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Starting Parsing the JSON string returned by Web Service
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }       
    }


    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

        JSONObject jObject;

        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {            

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;

            PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {            

                String[] from = new String[] { "formatted_address"};
                int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

                // Creating a SimpleAdapter for the AutoCompleteTextView            
                SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), result, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);             

                // Setting the adapter
                atvPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);
        }           
    }    




}
```

PlaceJSONParse class:

```
public class PlaceJSONParser {

    /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list */
    public List<HashMap<String,String>> parse(JSONObject jObject){      

        JSONArray jPlaces = null;
        try {           
            /** Retrieves all the elements in the 'places' array */
            jPlaces = jObject.getJSONArray("results");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /** Invoking getPlaces with the array of json object
         * where each json object represent a place
         */     
        return getPlaces(jPlaces);
    }


    private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jPlaces){
        int placesCount = jPlaces.length();
        List<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> place = null;   

        /** Taking each place, parses and adds to list object */
        for(int i=0; i<placesCount;i++){
            try {
                /** Call getPlace with place JSON object to parse the place */
                place = getPlace((JSONObject)jPlaces.get(i));
                placesList.add(place);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return placesList;
    }

    /** Parsing the Place JSON object */
    private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject jPlace){

        HashMap<String, String> place = new HashMap<String, String>();

//      String id="";
//      String reference="";
        String description="";      

        try {

            description = jPlace.getString("formatted_address");            
//          id = jPlace.getString("id");
//          reference = jPlace.getString("reference");

            place.put("formatted_address", description);
//          place.put("_id",id);
//          place.put("reference",reference);           

        } catch (JSONException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return place;
    }
}
```

CustomAutoCompleteTextView.class

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /** Returns the place description corresponding to the selected item */
    @Override
    protected CharSequence convertSelectionToString(Object selectedItem) {
        /** Each item in the autocompetetextview suggestion list is a hashmap object */
        HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String, String>) selectedItem;
        return hm.get("description");
    }

}
```

Comment: didnt i send you a working example?